# jQuery window bind focus

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
$(window).bind("focus", function() {
    $('input[name=myName]').focus();
});
```

But it was causing "too much recursion".  So I changed it to this:

```
$(window).one("focus", function() {
    $('input[name=myName]').focus();
});
```

But that of course only works the first time the window gets the focus.

Q: How do I write it so that every time the user toggles to another screen and back to this one, then *myName* has the focus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prevent the event from bubbling by assigning a handler to the inputs that calls `e.stopPropagation()`:

```
$(window).bind("focus", function() {
    $('input[name="myName"]').focus();
});
$('input[name="myName"]').focus(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

or just have your `window` function check the `e.target` to see where the event came from:

```
$(window).bind("focus", function(e) {
    if( e.target === window ) {
        $('input[name="myName"]').focus();
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT:** Added quotation marks around the value part of the attribute selector. This is mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Could something like this work?

```
function winFocus(){
    $(window).one("focus", function() {
        $('input[name="myName"]').focus();
    });
}

winFocus(); //first time

$(window).bind("blur",winFocus);
```